# $f \in L^2[a,b]$ and for all $g \in C[a,b]$ we have that $\int_a^b fg = 0$. Proof that $f=0$ a.e..

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Is my solution to Exercise 21 from Chapter 3 of the book "A user friendly introduction to Lebesgue measure and integration" by Nelson correct?

We know that we can approximate $f$ by a continuous function $g$ on $[a,b]$, i.e., for all $\epsilon > 0$ there is a continuous function $g$ such that $\|f-g\|_2 < \epsilon^2$.

By definition of the norm we have
\begin{align}
\int_a^b |f-g|^2 &< \epsilon \\
\int_a^b f^2-2fg+g^2  &< \epsilon.
\end{align}
By our assumption, $\int_a^b fg = 0$, so we have
\begin{align}
\int_a^bf^2 +\int_a^bg^2 < \epsilon.
\end{align}
As both terms must be nonnegative,
$$\int_a^bf^2 < \epsilon,$$
and $f^2=0$ a.e.. We conclude that $f = 0$ a.e.

Is this proof correct? It feels a bit hand-wavy at the last step.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Please note that you should write $\epsilon^2$ since $\int|f-g|^2=\|f-g\|_2^2$

Comment: Thanks! Actually I even have it like that in my notes :) Updating.

Comment: Yes, it's correct. You can also look at your proof as saying: If $f$ is orthogonal to all elements in a dense set (in your case $C[a,b]$), then $f=0$. Or put another way, the orthogonal complement of a dense set is $\{ 0\}$.

Comment: @Flo It is a nice correct proof. Ultimately, you are using the fact that $f\geq 0\;\text{a.e.,}\;f\in L^{1}(a,b),\;\int_{a}^{b}f\geq 0\Longrightarrow f=0\;\text{a.e.}.$  You must have already seen a proof of this fact in class before seeing this exercise. If not, then I recommend you prove it.

Comment: @Medo That's true. The book features this proof.